# Numerical calculation of non-linear LRC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, non-linear

I’m trying to solve a circuit using Excel and numerical calculations. Unfortunately, I’m a slightly stuck at the starting line and was hoping for some assistance here.

The circuit is presented below;
[image]

As the capacitor is already charged, there will only be current flowing in the right part of the circuit until the sine voltage source increases to above 800V so that the diode starts conducting. The initial current is zero, so the right part will essentially be a LRC discharge circuit the first 2.5 ms until the voltage source pass 800 V and starts charging the capacitor.

As this should be solved numerically, I have set a time step resolution of 20us. At t=0, the current is zero and voltage 800V.

How should I start calculating for t=20us for current i2 (which is equal to i3 the first 2.5ms) and voltage V2 ?

Comment: Use a simulator.

Comment: Of course I can use a simulator, but due to the nature of this task I want to carry it out in Excel.

Comment: Well I could use pen and paper or maybe a slide rule but I choose to use a calculator. Please justify your archaic approach to solving this problem.

Comment: I am using excel to enter generator and load data. The circuit is always identical, but component values changes. Excel will calculate each time step and plot all currents and voltages. Later, I will create a THD spectrum based on the equations from each time step.

Comment: provide the actual differential equations that represent the system plus the inputs and the outputs of the system.

Answer (score 0):

"Numerical" implies error (due to finite step size) so a first step is to decide on a tolerable error per step. 
If you arbitrarily decide, say, 1% is tolerable, then...

The t=0 calculation is easy - I2 is 0, so V(L3) = V2, establishing dI3/dt which you will use for the next step.

Then you know I2 at 20uS (from dI3/dt and dt) hence your new value of V2.

Here you have a choice. For the purpose of generating V2, you can assume I2 varies linearly between its old and new value and compute a mean value for it, which greatly improves accuracy for your new V2 value.  C * dV2 = I2(mean) * dt. Use this approach (a simple approach to numerical integration) for capacitors because they integrate charge.

With this new V2 and I2, you can work out the others I3, V(R3), V(L3) and use these to establish a new dI3/dt. Note that for V(R3) you want the final, not mean, value of I2.

Now, has V2 (or any other parameter changed by your error budget (1%) or more? If so. flag this, to warn the user the step size may be too small. The actual error is only loosely related to, and usually less than, less than the change in value, so this is a conservative approach to errors.

Rinse and repeat...

At the end of the day, knock the same simulation up in Spice and see how close this approach gets...

Edit : obvious mistake in formula : dV2 fixed to read C * dV2.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
So at t=0:
V2 = VL3 = 800V = (R3*i3) + (L * (di3/dt))
As i3=0, i get: 800V = L*(di3/dt).
With 20us timestep, i get that di3 = 400A. But how can that be true when i dont take voltage drop across the resistor into consideration?

Comment: I have built the circuit in LTspice, and values at t=20us is 764.47V and 1178 A.

Comment: Sorry, 3073 ampere.

Comment: dI3 = 400A is not accurate - but see first sentence. Multiplying by R3 gives you a specific voltage across R3, or a change in voltage across the inductor. Compare that change with your choice of error tolerance and you'll see whether or not you need a smaller step size or a more complex calculation.